# Vagarant/homestead does not create database unless

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I upgraded laravel/homestead box to version 11.1.0. Then a surprising happened: My DBs disappeared. How? I have no idea.
But then when I tried to reinstall the databases using Homestead.yaml, it did not work eventhough I added the list of databases in Homestead.yaml.

Here the what I did in Homestead.yaml:

```
    databases:
        - db00
        - db01
```

Then I ran "vagrant provision" but nothing changed in MySQL. "show databases;" displayed default tables only.

Then I activated the features:

```
     features:
        - mysql: true
        - mariadb: false
```

Then I ran "vagrant provision" and it worked. I had both databases (db00 and db01) in MySQL.
Here are the problems:

1. Based on [laravel/homestead documentation for laravel v8.x](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#installing-optional-features), there is no feature option for mysql. That caused the following error during provisioning:

   ```
   homestead: Invalid feature: mysql
   homestead: Ignoring feature: mariadb because it is set to false
   ```
2. Once I added the option "- mysql" to the Homestead.yaml, I received the following errors for MariaDB

   ```
   homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL / MariaDB Database: db00
   homestead: We didn't find a PID for mariadb, skipping $DB creation
   homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL / MariaDB Database: db01
   homestead: We didn't find a PID for mariadb, skipping $DB creation
   ```

Now here my question: What is going on? Without the feature option "- mysql" no database is created; no matter if I define the list under the databases. Once I add it, things work, databases are generated however, I get error that the feature is not valid. Also it is not included in the documentation.
Where am I going wrong? or if anyone has an explanation or a better solution?

Answer (score 5):

The answers to both of your questions is: because the documention is a bit misleading

For your first question, mysql is technically not an optional feature since is installed by default. However, as of `v11.3.0` in order to provision custom databases it must be listed under the features section in the `Homestead.yaml`:

```
features:
    - mysql: true
```

due to only running the provisioning script if `mysql` is specifically enabled:
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v11.3.0/scripts/homestead.rb

For your second question, the error message is displayed due to the way that the `create-mysql.sh` script was implemented in `v11.0.0`:
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v11.0.0/scripts/create-mysql.sh

```
if [ -z "$mariadb" ]
then
      # Skip Creating MariaDB database
      echo "We didn't find a PID for mariadb, skipping \$DB creation"
else
      mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$DB\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
fi
```

With the configuration you are using the `if [ -z "$mariadb" ]` condition will always be true because the process id of `mariadbd` will never be found since it is not enabled. Therefore the `We didn't find a PID for mariadb, skipping $DB creation` message will always be displayed even though the databases are succesfully created for mysql. Technically that is correct based on the way the script is coded, but it is also a bit confusing.

Also as for why your databases disappeared when upgrading, assuming you were following these instructions:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#updating-homestead

The `vagrant destroy` command will completely remove the homestead box and rebuild it. Therefore any data or other custom configuration will be lost unless it is configured to backup the data:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#database-backups

Comment: just saying is a good PR to push

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue recently with Homestead 12.3.0 and solved it by editing my `Homestead.yaml` with the following:

```
...

databases:
    - homestead
    - my_database

features:
    # - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - "mysql"

...
```

Then I ran `vagrant reload --provision`, and did not see the MariaDB error anymore.

To confirm you can SSH into the vagrant box, and log into MySQL (`homestead` / `secret`). In my case I found the database had been created correctly.